# Elisp: sleep-for doesn't block when running a test in ert

Tags: emacs, elisp, ert

I'm trying to set up some tests using ert that need to sleep for a background process to proceed. I've tried using `sleep-for` and `accept-process-output`. Neither is reliable. Here is a small example.

This test just sleeps for 5 seconds and then checks that at least 3 seconds have passed. Using `sleep-for` it finishes immediately and fails. If the `shell-command` is uncommented is takes the expected 5 seconds and succeeds! What is going on here?

```lisp
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time))))
    ;(shell-command "sleep 5")
    (sleep-for 5)
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

EDIT:

There must have been something strange in my environment when I tested the previous example. This slightly changed example contains a background process like the one I need to test, and fails. I tested it both interactively and using the command:

```
emacs --batch -l example.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
```

```lisp
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time))))
    (start-process "echo" "*echo*" "echo" "hello world")
    (sleep-for 5)
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

Output is:

```
Test timetest condition:
    (ert-test-failed
     ((should
       (< now
          (- ... 3)))
      :form
      (< 55177 55174)
      :value nil))
   FAILED  1/1  timetest

Ran 1 tests, 0 results as expected, 1 unexpected (2013-02-05 09:57:29+0000)

1 unexpected results:
   FAILED  timetest
```

EDIT2:

New version that seems to indicate process output is sufficient to interrupt `sleep-for`:

```lisp
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time))))
    (start-process "yes" "*yes*" "yes")
    (sleep-for 1) ;; This sleep-for may be interrupted by process *output*
    (sleep-for 5) ;; This sleep-for is also interrupted
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

EDIT3:

With a heavy heart, I post another version:

```lisp
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time)))
        (process-connection-type nil))
    (start-process "tmp" "*tmp*" "bash" "-c" "sleep 1; echo hi")
    (sleep-for 5)
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

It seems clear that `sleep-for` cannot be relied upon to block.

Comment: This is probably operating system specific, which environment are you using?

Comment: Seem to remember sleep-for not working on windows

Comment: I've tried the above on OS X and Linux. @wvxvw: why would it be useful if `sleep-for` was redefined?

Comment: This fails due to errors in start-process. Delivered arg "echo" is not a programm, but a shell-builtin - "shell" should be accepted as program here.

Comment: On what platform? I have `/bin/echo` on Fedora. Just replace echo with any other command that prints some like `date`.

Comment: The manual seems to say the opposite: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Waiting.html

"Use sleep-for when you wish to guarantee a delay."

Comment: @wvxvw can you please explain what you mean by `sleep-for` being async?

Comment: @wvxvw not sure about that, because `sleep-for` seems to be specifically about blocking, which has to be synchronous. I don't anything about ert though.

Comment: As I wrote, this is an Emacs bug. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308019/780703) for the details. *Don't attempt dirty, hackish workarounds.* You'll shoot yourself in the foot, sooner or later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `sleep-for` is interrupted when process exits.

Following test is failed, because `sleep-for` is interrupted after 2 second.

```
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time))))
    (start-process "sleep" "*sleep*" "sleep" "2") ;; Fail
    (sleep-for 5)
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

But following test is passed, because `sleep-for` is interrupted after 4 second.

```
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time))))
    (start-process "sleep" "*sleep*" "sleep" "4") ;; Success
    (sleep-for 5)
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

So I think you can write test as below

```
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time))))
    (start-process "echo" "*echo*" "echo" "hello world")
    (sleep-for 1) ;; This sleep-for may be interrupted by process exited
    (sleep-for 5) ;; This sleep-for can sleep 5 seconds
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

*EDIT1*

2nd test is passed by setting `process-connection-type` to `nil`.
(But I cannot understand this behavior)

```
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (cadr (current-time)))
        (process-connection-type nil))
    (start-process "yes" "*yes*" "yes")
    (sleep-for 5)
    (should (< now (- (cadr (current-time)) 3)))))
```

Please see [document](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html)

*EDIT2*

In 3rd test, we need 3 `sleep-for` because `sleep-for` is interrupted 2 times, 
But this is fragile. So I write test as below. This test can be passed
if `sleep-for` is interrupted as many times.
And I use `float-time` instead of `current-time`
because 2nd element of `current-time` may wrap arround.

```
(ert-deftest timetest ()
  (let ((now (float-time))
        (process-connection-type nil))
    (start-process "tmp" "*tmp*" "bash" "-c" "sleep 1; echo hi")
    (while (< (- (float-time) now) 5)
      (sleep-for 1))
    (should (< now (- (float-time) 3)))))
```

Comment: This looks very fragile to me. See my "EDIT2" example where I can break it by switching to the `yes` command that continuously outputs.

Comment: Please see "EDIT2" of my answer

Comment: `float-time` is a good replacement, thanks! I didn't know about that function. I'm going to accept your answer at this point, although if the background process keeps outputting this may not be much better than a busy-wait loop. This seems like a painful workaround to me, and a bug in either `sleep-for` or the documentation of it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I just copied into *scratch* and ran that test with `ert-run-tests-interactively`. I can't reproduce your issue. Do you have an older version of the test lingering in memory?

*Edit*: I'm using Emacs 24.2.1 on OS X 10.8

*Update*: Running your updated code. Something very strange is going on. About 1/4 of my runs are suceeding.

*Update*: I can verify @syohex's answer: adding a second call `sleep-for` works for me.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I probably had something strange in my environment. I've added a slightly modified version that fails in a fresh copy of emacs run in batch mode or interactively.

Comment: Please see "EDIT2" where I can break it again.

Answer (score 2):

This bug will be fixed in the next Emacs (25.1? 24.6??). See [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=commitdiff;h=3bea77f65504ee7c4364c300fd1f7d699e2866ac) in Jun 2015. (I haven't actually tried it, though.)

Until it gets fixed, use

```
(call-process "/usr/bin/sleep" nil nil nil "<seconds>")
```

instead of `sleep-for'. This is reliable.

Bug reports are found in [original](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15990) (#15990) and [duplicate](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20935) (#20935), where the fix was reported.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/rejeep/ert-async.el

Then you can do something like this:

```
(ert-deftest-async timetest (done)
  (call-async-command done))
```

Comment: I had a look at the README.md and I don't quite understand how this would work for my setting. Under `Usage`, I see "When the function async-call callbacks", but I don't know what `async-call` is, or what it means for it to "callback", and in the example what `async-call-1` and `async-call-2` are. Should I check for the results and call the `done-1`, `done-2` etc if they are not as expected?